# Using the rewrite library in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

There seems to be a rewriting tool in Isabelle which improves the quality of subst proofs. See [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/717e/4d3dbf9fe5fdef35df1c91152f1bd04d9b63.pdf) and the HOL/ex/Rewrite_Examples.thy in the distribution.

Now, I have a theorem like this:

> lemma rho_invariance_1: 
>     "add (ρ (x1,y1)) (x2,y2) = ρ (add (x1,y1) (x2,y2))"

and I realize that for proving it is more convinient to have this:

> lemma rho_invariance_1_points:
>     "add (ρ p1) p2 = ρ (add p1 p2)"

for that I can do:

> using rho_invariance_1 
>     apply(rewrite at "p1"  surjective_pairing)

My question is very simple, can I do several rewritings with the same command?

**Usage guide (for reference)**

Comment: so the goal in the above examples is to prove the second variant from the gone above

Comment: No. `rewrite` performs only one substitution at a time, unlike `subst` where you can specify several positions, e.g., `subst (1 3 4)`.

Comment: @AndreasLochbihler that's unfortunate, thanks for the answer

Comment: on the other hand, you can specify several patterns which is quite convenient and with subst this doesnt work